# When does function stack of parameter function unwinds?

Tags: c++

Supposing I have two functions, one like:

```
const char* getstr()
{
  std::string s = "somestring";
  return s.c_str();
}
```

second like:

```
void func(int x, const char* str)
{
    std::cout <<"x="<<x <<", str=" <<str<<std::endl;
}
```

And now suppose 'func()' with something like

```
func(100,getstr());
```

My question is when will the function stack for function "getstr()" be unwinded ?
After the body of "func()" is executed or before the body execution happens ?

I am asking this because some genius in my team wrote this type of "getstr()" function. and somehow the system is not crashing.

My understanding was that the stack for function "getstr()" will be unwinded as soon as that parameter is evaluated. But if that was true the code would have crashed and it is not happening.

Can someone help me what c++ standard says ?

Comment: It happens when `getstr` ends. You have undefined behavior, anything can happen, including appearing to work as you would expect.

Comment: Hint: undefined behavior means anything can happen, unpredictably.  That includes: crashing, deleting your harddrive, and even pretending to work a thousand times in a row, then opening youtube on the 1001th try.

Comment: `some genius in my team wrote this type of "getstr()" function` Is this function exactly what they wrote? They may be allocating to the heap/free store

Comment: You were merely (un)lucky. Undefined behavior does not guarantee your system will crash. If I run your snippet, it prints garbage. More reliably, try running through *Valgrind*, it reports an error as well. Most reliably: Write a small test case with a custom string where you augment the destructor to print a message and also print a message in `func` before it uses its argument.

Comment: thanks guys. just needed some confirmation. I appreciate your comments.

Comment: An explanation why *probably* it seems to work: the things that are in stack would be overwritten only if more/deeper calls are made. In this case there are none, so the stack based string object was left untouched. If it allocated memory dynamically, there was no new suitable allocation that would've overwritten that block either. But as has been said, undefined behaviour can't be trusted to be the same any two times. This is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` gets destroyed before `getstr` returns. The pointer that `getstr` returns is dangling.